Python singleton pattern with type hints
I have been trying to use the Singleton pattern in Python with proper type hints.
Here is my attempt
from typing import Any, TypeVar, override


T = TypeVar('T', bound='SingletonBase')


class Singleton(type):
    _instances: dict[type[T], T] = {}  # type variable T has no meaning in this context

    @override
    def __call__(cls: type[T], *args: Any, **kwargs: dict[str, Any]) -> T:
        if cls not in cls._instances:  # Access to generic instance variable through class is ambiguous
            instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            cls._instances[cls] = instance # Access to generic instance variable through class is ambiguous
        return cls._instances[cls]  # Expression of type T is incompatible with return type T@__call__


class SingletonBase(metaclass=Singleton):
    pass

I get a lot of complaints from the type checker. (I have annotate my code with the complaints as comments)
I found this answer Type hinting for generic singleton?
But that only handles annotations for the return type. I would like to understand what's going on here and learn how to implement the Singleton pattern with proper type hints.

"I have been trying to use the Singleton pattern in Python with proper type hints." Why?

just define a function that returns an instance, and make the class "private" by naming it with a single leading underscore. All the other rigamarole with metaclasses is totally pointless and over-engineered and gives you nothing that the above approach doesn't

@chepner primarily caching. My Service class is expensive to initialize. So I would avoid having to instantiate it everywhere it's needed.
I didn't know if having a global variable is a good idea for this.

A singleton can’t be type-hinted, in the sense that type-hints don’t offer the ability to use mechanisms such as is comparisons to offer type-narrowing (e.g. you can’t replicate None for another Python construct). There’s a few issues in your attempt here, but that’s not anything to do with singletons.

Here is the most reasonable way to define a "singleton" pattern in Python:
class _Foo:
    _instance: "_Foo" = None

def Foo() -> _Foo:
    if _Foo._instance is None:
        _Foo._instance = _Foo()
    return _Foo._instance

The above plays nice with type-annotations, doesn't' require a metaclass, and gives you the exact same guarantee that someone won't instantiate multiple instances of your class (which is no guarantee, since even with your metaclass example, someone can define multiple instances of your class).
Or as pointed out in the comments, even more simply,
import functools

class _Foo:
    pass

@functools.cache
def Foo() -> _Foo:
    return _Foo()


Even these shenanigans with class private var aren't necessary if you don't need arguments: just functools.cache its factory!

@STerliakov true that is totally valid

Or even simply Foo = functools.cache(_Foo).
